# Custom Flow type definitions apparently not being read

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype, flow-typed

I have run the following:

```
$ npm install flow-bin
$ yarn global add flow-typed
$ flow-typed install
```

Which correctly populates `./flow-typed/npm/` with definitions, some are valid and some are stubs.

But these type definitions for libraries are not showing up in VSCode (with the official flowtype module installed, `flowtype.flow-for-vscode`—everything coming from the libraries show as typed with `any` on mouse hover), and running the flow checker from the command line returns no errors, even if I deliberately mis-use a library, such as:

```
const express = require('express');
express.chicken();
```

All of the sections in my `./flowconfig` file are empty.
I have also tried adding my own definitions to the `./flow-typed/` directory (not the `npm` subdir) to no avail.

Does anyone have suggestions as to what I could be doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have fixed itself when I restarted my laptop.